# regex to allow certain input values

Tags: regex

I want to allow input values as A+,B+,A-,B- or 2 decimal values like 100.00, 90.0 like this

how to write regex for above input? simply I want to allow grades(A+,A-,B+,B-),decimal values (10.05,20.00).

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: /^^(a+|A+|b+|B+)/i.test(value)

Comment: but how to allow above and decimals values

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question contains nothing about this plugin.  It doesn't even contain any jQuery.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex will helpful to you:

```
[AB][+-]|\d{2}\.\d{2}
```

Description and Demo At: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM6yY0/1)

Answer (score 1):

For what I am seeing, I would use this regex (I bet you can optimize it).

```
^([A-GOa-go][+-])|((\d{1,2}(?!\d)\.\d{2}|100\.00),(\d{1,2}(?!\d)\.\d{2}|100\.00))$
```

[Here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP6oS1/4)

Comment: but that float values should be less than 100 only

Comment: @muralikalpana So your example is wrong ? You provided 100.00 which is equal to 100 (not less). Float with 2 precision ?

Comment: (A|B|C|D|E|F|G|O|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|o)[+-]|\d{3}\.\d{2}

Comment: yes it allow 100 or lessthan 100. but that value should be decimal

Comment: @muralikalpana ok. And the grades jump from G to O (H-M excluded ?)

Comment: yes i am allowing a,b,c,d,e,f,g,o only. is there any way to  restrict less than100 value

Comment: @muralikalpana There is but the float values giving me issues :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104630/discussion-between-stilleur-and-muralikalpana).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([AB][+-]|(100|\d{2})\.\d{2})
```

This, in my opinion, will work for what you are expecting

Online test : [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/3cssf)

**EDIT :**

Following what you are expecting for, i suggest you this regex :

```
^([AB][+-]|(100|\d{2})\.\d{2})$
```

Will match only if the entire string matches, and no longer return a 02.00 match for 102.00 (for example)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it is allowing 102.00 also

Comment: RegExr does not match the entire string "102.00" but actually matches "02.00". You have to test if the entire string matches up.
I update the online test, showing what i said (only 02.00 highlights) : [link](http://regexr.com/3cssf)

Comment: The regex matches those strings, but the tester i provide you seems a bit laggy.
I tried on : http://www.regexpal.com/
and : https://www.debuggex.com/
You can find much more regex tester on the internet to test yours

Comment: Words A+, A-, B+ and B- are already allowed, i actually don't understand the meaning of the question.
Do you mean you want to match several words at a time?
Such like this regex should match "A+,B-,10.00,53.89"
Or only one by one (matching an input containing only, for example, "B+")
This is getting confused, bring more details, regex requires to be very clear and very precise on your expectations.